# Bootstrap 4 - When shrinking a screen with card group of 4 cards, how to split cards evently between rows?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

With a card group of 4 cards in a single row, how do I make it such that as the screen gets smaller, it goes straight from 4 cards in a single row into 2 cards in the first row and 2 cards in the second row while skipping 3 cards in the first row and a single long card in the second row.

Here's an example of my HTML with bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s10 offset-s1 m6 l4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
                        <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus,
                        accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur
                        quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore
                        necessitatibus optio rem.
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s10 offset-s1 m6 l4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
                        <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus,
                        accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur
                        quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore
                        necessitatibus optio rem.
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s10 offset-s1 m6 l4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
                        <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus,
                        accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur
                        quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore
                        necessitatibus optio rem.
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s10 offset-s1 m6 l4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
                        <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus,
                        accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur
                        quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore
                        necessitatibus optio rem.
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it looks like you are using [Materialize grid](https://materializecss.com/grid.html) classes instead of [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) classes.

You can use `col-6 col-md-3` for all the card parent element so that it splits into two by default and splits into 4 after it reached medium screen breakpoint.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
            <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
          </div>
          <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus, accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore necessitatibus optio rem.
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
            <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
          </div>
          <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus, accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore necessitatibus optio rem.
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
            <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
          </div>
          <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus, accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore necessitatibus optio rem.
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="icon-block">
          <div class="card-title text-center mt-3">
            <h4 class="center">Item</h4>
          </div>
          <h5 class="card-title text-center mt-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia eos, neque veritatis et repellendus, accusantium nisi soluta repellat, quidem aspernatur quae saepe tempora ad? Nam earum labore necessitatibus optio rem.
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```